# Excel Reverse Match

Tags: excel, match

I'm trying to find a way to do a reverse match in Excel. I have a column of TRUE/FALSE statements and I need to find a way to find both a match and a reverse match within this one column to find the difference between `TRUE` statements in both directions.

```
True
False
False
False
True
False
False
True
```

In this scenario from the perspective of the middle True statement the normal `MATCH` function going down would return a number of 4. I am trying to find an additional match function that would look upward to the `TRUE` statement and return a value of 5

Comment: Could you add a some sample data/desired output? Just a little info on what you mean by 'reverse match' and what you want your output to look like.

Comment: I believe that you cannot do this without resorting to vba. All native functions in excel access ranges top-to-bottom and/or left-to-right.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty:

`A1:A7`: TRUE/FALSE
`A8`: Array formula: `{=LARGE(IF(A1:A7=TRUE;ROW(A1:A7);"");1)}`

The result will be the row number of the nearest `TRUE` from below.
The formula is inserted by Shift-Ctrl-Enter in a formula window. Curled brackets are inserted by Excel, not by a user.

If you need the shift from the last `TRUE`: 
`{=LARGE(IF(A1:A7=TRUE;ROW(A1:A7);"");2)}`

Changing the last number in the formula moves you to the n-th `TRUE` from below.

Replacing `LARGE` with `SMALL` will give the row numbers from above. So it would possible to find the shift between relevant combinations by combining the formulae.