# How to find parent in an indented hierarchy?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a sheet in excel with an indented hierarchy of items as shown below. 
Each item is indented (four spaces per indent) to show how it fits into the overall hierarchy. 
I have been able to create a "Level" column that translates the indentation level into a number.

```
    +------------+-------+--------+
    |    Item    | Level | Parent |
    +------------+-------+--------+
    | P1         |     1 | N/A    |
    |     P2     |     2 | P1     |
    |     P3     |     2 | P1     |
    |         P4 |     3 | P3     |
    |     P5     |     2 | P1     |
    |         P6 |     3 | P5     |
    +------------+-------+--------+
```

What I want to do is generate the "Parent" column above, which uses the "level" information to display each item's parent.
I think that this would need to be done with a loop that would do this for each item X :

```
    -Find level info for X
    -Find (levelx-1) which would equal the parent item's level
    -Search upward for the first row with a level equal to (levelx-1)
    -Find the item number in that row
    -Write item number in adjacent cell to X
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to translate this idea into VBA.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Just to clarify, the solution does not have to be VBA. In fact it would be better if it weren't.

Comment: A [reverse match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189085/excel-reverse-match) might help. With that, you will have the row number, which can be used in an index formula to get the desired result. Give me a minute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, assuming the above table starts in cell A1, useful data starts in row 2. This formula will do the trick:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MAX(IF($B$2:$B2=B2-1,ROW($B$2:$B2),"")))
```

Enter this in cell `C2` as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter), then pull it down. The first one will obviously be an error (not `#NA` but `#VALUE`).

**How it works:**

```
IF($B$2:$B2=B2-1,ROW($B$2:$B2),"")
```

This creates an array with the row numbers for values with one level lower than the actual value. To examine only the values **above** the current row, you need to use expanding ranges, hence the `$B$2:$B2` style references.

The `MAX` function gets the maximum of these rows, which is the closest to our current cell. Now we have the row number. All we need now is a formula to extract the data from column `A` from the indicated row. This is what `INDEX` does.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution and thorough explanation!

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand how this formula works, so after figuring it out (ok, my wife helped me a bit) I'd like to share an idiot-proof explanations for other Excel-dummies like me. Here we go:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MAX(IF($B$2:$B2=B2-1,ROW($B$2:$B2),"")))
```

means:

1. Among values in range `$B$2:$B2` find all values that equal to
   `B2-1`.
2. If you find them, list the row numbers with value equal to
   `B2-1`. (ROW)
3. From the list of the row numbers, pick the highest
   row number (lets call it number `X`). (MAX)
4. Return the value which is in the line number `X` in the range `$A$1:$A$7`

   (Warning! Your range has to start in the row no. 1, so that the row number is the same as the line number in your range. Otherwise - you have to adapt the formula.)