# Using Excel, how to find parent cell in a hierarchy?

Tags: excel

Am running Excel 2013 on Windows 10 with 16 GB memory.

I have a hierarchical structure similar to figure 1 below. My structure is 1000+ rows and as deep as 27 levels.

[image: hierarchy]

**For a "tree" as depicted above, how to identify the parent of a cell?**

Here's what I've done so far. Using conditional formatting, and this formula:

```
  =AND(A1<>"",OFFSET(A1,1,1)="")
```

I am able to identify the leaf nodes of the tree, as shown in figure 2 below.

[image: conditional formatting]

Now I need to find the immediate ancestor (parent) of every cell (child) in the tree (with the exception of the first row that does not have a parent).

Figure 3 (below) shows an example done manually:

[image]

Further, I can associate the tree with an outline.
Then I am able to count the number of decimals in the outline in order to track level changes using this formula:

```
  =LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",""))
```

as shown in figure 4 below:

[image]

**How to programmatically accomplish what was done manually in figure 3?**

**For each row (recorded in a column outside of the tree), print the location of the cell that is the parent of the cell.**

Here is a similar question that manually provides "level" information.

[How to find parent in an indented hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753817/how-to-find-parent-in-an-indented-hierarchy)

In my case, I need to work from an outline (as shown) or by using a formula for Conditional formatting.

Comment: Given a `cell`, its parent is `cell.offset(0,-1).end(xlUp)`.

Comment: Would you show your solution in a proposed answer? I'm not sure how to apply your comment to my sample? Should I put the sample on a Google Spreadsheet and share the URL?

Comment: It's a VBA expression that returns the parent given the cell. I'm not sure how to translate `End(xlUp)` into a formula, it would probably involve a complex, confusing and slow construct. If you're happy with some VBA, create a function that accepts a `c` and returns `c.offset(0,-1).end(xlUp)` and use it from the sheet, otherwise it will probably not help you.

Comment: Sounds promising. I had hoped to avoid VBA as I am not a VBA programmer, but will accept it if it works. Would you publish the script so that I can copy/paste into the VBA editor and try it? I would like the values to appear in their own column, either to the left or the right of the hierarchy.

Comment: Alternatively, if I understand you correctly, I can copy the source to a new tab and apply the VBA to the new (copied) tab.

Comment: TY. Gimme several hours to apply this to some big hierarchies. BBTY.

Comment: I've posted the formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your rules, the parent of a cell is the first non-empty cell, bottom to top, in the column immediately to the left:

```
public function GetParentCell(byval c as range) as range
  set GetParentCell = c.offset(0,-1).end(xlUp)
end function
```

Having put this in a module, you can use it from the sheet, e.g.

```
=CELL("address", GetParentCell(D4))
```

to display the address of the parent of `D4`.

If you want to avoid VBA completely, you have to find a way to convert `End(xlUp)` into a formula which may prove difficult because Excel lookups [work from top to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29967567/11683) and you want the other way round. If I was to do that, I would start from [Last non-empty cell in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5441885/11683).

Given that the hierarchy is contained in `A1:G19`:

- In `H1`, put:

  ```
  =MATCH("x",$A1:$G1,0)
  ```
- In `I1`, put

  ```
  =CELL("address",INDEX(INDEX($A$1:$G$19,1,H1-1):INDEX($A$1:$G$19,ROW(),H1-1),MAX((INDEX($A$1:$G$19,1,H1-1):INDEX($A$1:$G$19,ROW(),H1-1)<>"")*(ROW(INDEX($A$1:$G$19,1,H1-1):INDEX($A$1:$G$19,ROW(),H1-1))))))
  ```

  as an array formula (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

  The credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5442955/11683 because it is nothing more than a dynamic version of `=INDEX(A:A,MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))))`.
- Drag everything down.

The formula in column `I` returns the parent of each cell as a true reference which is then examined by the `CELL()` function to show the address. You can remove the `CELL()` and use the calculated reference in a different way.

Comment: Am I doing this correctly. The H column works correctly. The I column returns the correct column. But the value of the row is always $1. For example, H12 is 7 (column G). But I12 is $F$1, when it should be $F$11. Similarly, H4 is 4 (correct). However I4 is $C$1 but should be $C$3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You missed the "as an array formula (CTRL+Shift+Enter)", didn't you.